# Load Runner in Java Applet based Desktop application

Tags: loadrunner

I want to load test a Java Applet based Desktop application using HP load runner. For this i tried with sample application when i do the protocol advisor it says sample application uses the Java Over http and Java Record and replay protocols. In Load runner i was unable to record my application together with these protocols. When i try to run with single java protocol script is not generating in my LR Vugen. Do i have any option to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This question seems remarkably similar to questions asked and addressed and addressed comprehensively within the past couple of weeks on Facebook.  I would refer you to the following facebook group

https://www.facebook.com/groups/HPLoadRunner/